# Regular expression for filename in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

I have a form and I upload a file and I have to verify that the filename has this format `input##.txt`, where `##` are digits.

Until now I've had a validator on the upload input and the regular expression that I found is `input\d{2}\.txt`, but is not enough because the FileUpload control's filename looks like this :

**C:\Documents and Settings\xyz\Desktop\input01.txt**

and I need to validate only the part with `input01.txt`.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
var regex = new Regex("input\d{2}.txt", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var isValid = regex.Matches(fileName);
```